# Retrieving month number in fiscal year using lubridate

Tags: r, lubridate

I'm hoping to retrieve the month number from a fiscal year that starts in November (i.e. the first day of the fiscal year is November 1st). The following code provides my ***desired*** output, borrowing the `week_start` syntax of `lubridate::wday`, where `year_start` is analogous to `week_start`:

```
library('lubridate')
dateToRetrieve = ymd('2017-11-05')
#output: [1] "2017-11-05"
monthFromDate = month(dateToRetrieve, year_start=11)
#output: [1] 1
```

Since this functionality doesn't yet exist, I'm looking for an alternative solution that provides the same output. Adding `period(10, units="month")` to each date does not work because the length of different months leads to issues translating between months (e.g. March 31st minus a month = February 31st, which doesn't make sense).

I checked a somewhat similar question on the lubridate github [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/lubridate/issues/113), but didn't see any solutions. Does anyone have an idea that will provide my desired functionality?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1) lubridate** Below `x` can be a character vector or a `Date` vector:

```
x <- "2017-11-05" # test data
(month(x) - 11) %% 12 + 1
## [1] 1
```

**2) Base R** To do this with only base R first calculate the month number giving `mx` as shown and then perform the same computation:

```
mx <- as.POSIXlt(x)$mon + 1
(mx - 11) %% 12 + 1
## [1] 1
```

Comment: What happens if the date is in the form "2017-Dec-12?! Asking for learning purposes.

Comment: The date must of the form in the question; otherwise, transform it first, e.g. `x <- ymd("2017-Dec-12")`

Comment: Thanks. What's the easiest way to transform these kinds of dates?! Gave me a hard time recently.

Comment: Added that to my last comment.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was hoping for.

Answer (score 1):

It is a not pretty way... but you could create a vector range of months starting at November, call the full `month` of the date object, then `match` the two objects together to get the vector position.

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library('lubridate'))

x <- format(ISOdate(2004,1:12,1),"%B")[c(11,12,1:10)]

match(as.character(month(ymd('2017-11-05'), label = TRUE, abbr = FALSE)), x)
#> [1] 1
match(as.character(month(ymd('2017-01-15'), label = TRUE, abbr = FALSE)), x)
#> [1] 3
match(as.character(month(ymd('2017-05-01'), label = TRUE, abbr = FALSE)), x)
#> [1] 7
```